# Firestore collection to array of objects with Firebase v9

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating a React Web Application. And I want to transform a firebase collection with documents into an array of objects. Every object in the array corresponding to a document in the collection. It would make my life easier. The reason why I'm asking is that i haven't been able to find a solution that works with Firebase **Version 9**.

Comment: What have you tried? You say that "The reason why I'm asking is that i haven't been able to find a solution that works with Firebase Version 9.". Did you succeed with V8?

Comment: If you check the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection), you can use `getDocs()` to get a QuerySnapshot and then use `const arr = querySnapshot.docs.map((d) => ({ id: d.id, ...d.data() }))`. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec No i actually haven't tried with Firebase V8, but it would be nice to have the newest version of Firebase.

Comment: But did you try something? It would be nice to see what you have tried.

Comment: I think @Dharmaraj 's solution is the best way to go

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `getDocs()` with your [CollectionReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.collectionreference) or a [Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.query) and then map an array from the [QuerySnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.querysnapshot) received as shown below:

```
const q = collection(db, "users")
const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q) 

const arr = querySnapshot.docs.map((d) => ({ id: d.id, ...d.data() }))
```

Checkout the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection) for more information.

Comment: `querySnapshot.docs` did the trick. i forgot to add `.docs`. Thanks!